# Error "Access denied" when deploying app to the phone

Tags: c#, cordova, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2015

I have my Windows 8.1 Phone attached to my computer, with the screen unlocked.

In both Visual Studio 2013 or 2015, when I open the SLN file created by cordova, which contains a single project, and click the "> Device" button to run the project on the device, the error I get is:

```
Schweregrad Code    Beschreibung    Projekt Datei   Zeile   Unterdrückungszustand
Fehler              Zugriff verweigert              0
```

which roughly translates to

```
Severity    Code    Description     Project File    Line    Suppression state
Error               Access denied                   0
```

This is a really useful error message with many details, thank you for that, Microsoft.

Has someone already come across this issue and knows how to fix it?

Some months ago (before I installed Visual Studio 2015, added certain Windows Updates and added Windows Phone SDK to VS2015) it worked in VS2013 with the same computer/phone/cable/cordova/app configuration.

Comment: Have you tried to create a dummy WP8 App and deploy it? You would then know that the Computer/Phone/cable are not the problem...

Comment: OK, I made a new app, and in the process I was told that I had not registered as a developer (which I had). I re-registered, re-unlocked my phone ([which only works if the phone's wifi is enabled](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devfish/2014/01/03/set-date-and-time-error-unlocking-a-windows-phone/)) and now it works.